# Open set in $\ell^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $a=(a_n)_n\subset(0,\infty)$ be a sequence and $S^{(a)}:=\{(x_n)_n\in\ell^2:\lvert x_n\rvert\  <a_n \forall n \}$.
I want to prove that $S^{(a)}$ is open in $\ell^2$ iff $\inf_{n\in\mathbb{N}} a_n>0$ but don't know where to  start.

Comment: Maybe to demonstrate a neighborhood for a given point of the set you want to prove being open?

Comment: Use \ell for $\ell$ when discussing $\ell^p$ spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: For the left to right direction it’s probably easier to show the contrapositive; suppose that $\inf_{n\in\Bbb N}a_n=0$, and show that $S^{(a)}$ is *not* open. For this you want to find an $x\in S^{(a)}$ such that no open ball centred at $x$ lies entirely inside $S^{(a)}$. In fact it turns out that you don’t have to search hard for such an $x$: *any* $x\in S^{(a)}$ will work. Specifically, let $x=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle\in S^{(a)}$, let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary, and show that there is a $y=\langle y_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle\in \ell^2\setminus S^{(a)}$ such that $\|y-x\|_2<\epsilon$. I’ve left a further hint in the spoiler-protected block below.

> You can choose $y$ so that $y_n=x_n$ for all but one $n\in\Bbb N$, if you choose that one $n$ so that $a_n$ is small enough.

For the right to left direction, assume that $\inf_{n\in\Bbb N}a_n>0$, suppose that $x=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle\in S^{(a)}$; then $\sum_{n\in\Bbb N}x_n^2<\infty$, and $|x_n|<a_n$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$, and you want to show that some open nbhd of $x$ in $\ell^2$ is contained in $S^{(a)}$. You might as well try for a basic open nbhd: you want an $\epsilon>0$ such that $y\in S^{(a)}$ whenever $\|y-x\|_2<\epsilon$, i.e., whenever

$$\left(\sum_{n\ge 0}(y_n-x_n)^2\right)^{1/2}<\epsilon\;.\tag{1}$$

Note that if $(1)$ holds, then $|y_n-x_n|<\epsilon$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$. It will also help to remember that $\lim_{n\to\infty}|x_n|=0$.

Comment: If the downvoter has identified an actual error, a comment identifying it would be both courteous and far more helpful than the downvote by itself. If, on the other hand, the downvoter is merely one of those who don’t believe in helping the lost, I expect no better.

Comment: One would think that the reputation cost would deter casual downvoting...

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I tried for a while now and was able to do the direction from left to right, but am stuck at the other one. I'm sorry if this should be obvious but at the moment I can't see how to pick the $\epsilon$, could you please give me a further hint?

Comment: @see: In order to get $y\in S^{(a)}$, you need to be sure that $|y_n|<a_n$ for each $n$. You know that you’re going to have $|y_n-x_n|<\epsilon$, and that $|x_n|<a_n$, so you’ll have $|y_n|\le|y_n-x_n|+|x_n|$. What if you knew that $|y_n-x_n|<a_n-|x_n|$?

Comment: I assume I have to take $\epsilon=\inf_n a_n$ at the moment.

Comment: @see: You’re thinking in the right direction now, but it’s not quite that simple. You need to look at the $a_n-|x_n|$ instead. (That’s why the final sentence in my answer is there: it really is important that if $\inf_na_n>0$, the $|x_n|$ can’t get arbitrarily close to the $a_n$ values.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Alright, so I take $\epsilon :=\inf_n (a_n-|x_n|)$ and with this I get for any $m$: $|y_m|\le |y_m-x_m|+|x_m|<\inf_n (a_n-|x_n|)+|x_m|\le a_m-|x_m|+|x_m|=a_m$.

Comment: @see: That’s right, though if you’re writing it up carefully, you should probably include some brief comment explaining why that infimum is positive.

Comment: @see: Yes. And if $a=\inf_na_n$, we know that for sufficiently large $n$ we must have $|x_n|<\frac{a}2$ (why?). That means that $\inf_n(a_n-|x_n|)$ is no smaller than the minimum of $\frac{a}2$ and the minimum of $a_n-|x_n|$ over some finite initial segment of the sequence.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott The statement in your first statement is true because $x_n\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: @see: Yes, exactly. And now you’re pretty much home free, I think.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Got it. Thank you very much.

Comment: @see: You’re very welcome.